# Como fazer algoritmo de tabuada rodar novamente se o usuário escolher rodar de novo?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
from time import sleep
print('-=-'*20)
print('Tabuada da adição')
print('-=-'*20)
n = int(input('Insira um número: '))
n0 = n + 0 
n1 = n + 1
n2 = n + 2
n3 = n + 3
n4 = n + 4
n5 = n + 5
n6 = n + 6
n7 = n + 7
n8 = n + 8
n9 = n + 9
n10 = n + 10
sleep(2)
print('Aguarde um pouco enquanto estou carregando.....')
print('{}+0 = {}'.format(n, n0))
print('{}+1 = {}'.format(n, n1))
print('{}+2 = {}'.format(n, n2))
print('{}+3 = {}'.format(n, n3))
print('{}+4 = {}'.format(n, n4))
print('{}+5 = {}'.format(n, n5))
print('{}+6 = {}'.format(n, n6))
print('{}+7 = {}'.format(n, n7))
print('{}+8 = {}'.fomrat(n, n8))
print('{}+9 = {}'.format(n, n9))
print('{}+10 = {}'.format(n, n10))
r = str(input('Deseja escolher outro número ? '))
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema, seria colocar o seu código dentro de uma estrutura de um laço de repetição e manter a execução do programa em loop até que o usuário faça a opção de sair do programa.

Segue um exemplo de como pode ser implementado:

```
repetir = True
while repetir:
    #seu código
    entrada = input('Deseja executar novamente? (s/n)')
    if entrada[0].lower() == 'n':
        repetir = False
```

Para este exemplo utilizamos o laço de repetição [`while`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/statements/while.html), a função [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) da classe `str` e estamos extraindo a primeira posição do array, para fazer a decisão de exibir novamente.

Repare que desta forma a única maneira de parar a repetição é respondendo `"n"`, foi implementado desta maneira por simplicidade, essa implementação não vai considerar a resposta `"s"`, qualquer escolha do usuário (exceto a resposta <kbd>n</kbd>) vai fazer que haja uma nova repetição do código.